# Digital Image Processing Textbook with Specific Topics

Tags: image-processing, reference-request, image-registration, books

I am looking for a Digital Image Processing and analysis textbook, but there are specific topics that I would like the book to cover. Among other topics, I would like it to include a discussion of:

- (Orthonormal) basic functions
- Mahalanobis distance
- Subspaces
- Image registration
- Error accumulation
- Background estimation

What textbook(s) would you recommend?  I imagine this lack of a direct question is the reason for the two unhelpful downvotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fundamental book on image processing for electrical engineers is

- Jae S. Lim - Two-Dimensional Signal and Image Processing

A highly recommended one, again, for electrical engineers is

- Anil Jain - Fundamentals of Digital Image Processing

A hands-on book on basic practical image processing is

- Wilhelm Burger - Principles of Digital Image Processing

If specifically looking for machine vision, then have a look at

- [Bernd Jahne - Digital Image Processing](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540240358).

Answer (score 1):

This is the list I'd recommend:

- [Rafael C. Gonzalez, Richard E. Woods - Digital Image Processing](http://www.imageprocessingplace.com/)
  Great introductory book. Well written, a lot of examples. Though it is not deep in any of the fields.
- Alan C. Bovik - The Essential Guide to Image Processing
  A comprehensive book on many image processing related subjects. A Great book to skim through.
- [Richard Szeliski - Computer Vision - Algorithms and Applications](http://szeliski.org/Book/)
  Advanced book with many state of the art (Non Deep Learning) algorithms in Computer Vision. A great book. It is available on line for free.